# JavaScriptMVC and Ruby on Rails integration in one application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc

I have searched here, and only found one similar topic with no answers. I have worked on several JavaScript MVC projects, and I have an understanding of how it works. I am not as proficient in Ruby on Rails, but I am learning. Now I know that I have some code that calls Ruby controllers from JMVC. My question is how do I substitute Ruby views with JMVC views? Basically, instead of Ruby views, I want JMVC views to be called. Anyone has done this? Any sample code would be nice.

Comment: That's not how that works. Are you actually planning to serve different pages from the server? The right way is to load a single page from the server, then use JMVC for all the routing and views, fetching data from your Rails-based services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set up you jsMVC the usual way, you could swap you views/plugins, that would call up to the ruby controllers